# How to get rid of -Wpointer-arith

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers, pointer-to-pointer

This code:

```
void Pack::packUInteger(void **buffer, unsigned int payload){
    memcpy(*buffer, &payload, sizeof(unsigned int));
    *buffer += sizeof(unsigned int);    
}
```

yields this warning, that I would like to get rid off without telling the compiler to ignore it:

```
src/messaging/Pack.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Pack::packUInteger(void**, unsigned int)’:
src/messaging/Pack.cpp:33:10: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  *buffer += sizeof(unsigned int);
  ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

I know it should there needs to be a de-referencing and casting, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it correctly.

Thank you internet! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to verify that this is correct unless you show what the pointer is pointing at.

But given that you attempt to increment the pointer by `sizeof(unsigned int)`, it would make sense if `*buffer` points to an element of an array of `unsigned int`, and you attempt to increment the pointer to the next sibling.

A correct way to do that is:

```
auto ptr = static_cast<unsigned*>(*buffer);
*buffer = ptr + 1;
```

On the other hand, if if points to raw storage such as `std::byte`, a correct way is:

```
auto ptr = static_cast<std::byte*>(*buffer);
*buffer = ptr + sizeof payload;
```

Instead of using `void**`, I recommend following instead:

```
template <class T>
std::byte* pack(std::byte* buffer, T payload) {
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>);
    std::memcpy(buffer, std::addressof(payload), sizeof payload);
    return buffer + sizeof payload;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I don't have access to std::, as the code is supposed to run in Intel SGX enclaves :)  Other than that, your answer was really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @larslars None of `std::` stuff are absolutely necessary here. Use `unsigned char` instead of `std::byte`. Include `string.h` for `::memcpy`. You can implement a `nonstd::addressof` easily yourself. `std::is_trivially_copyable` is probably non-trivial to implement, but the assertion can be removed and the requirement documented separately.

Comment: Yes thanks it does work without it. We have our own memcpy and I'm considering an addressof implementation. I will be adding sanity checks (memory bounds, range checking etc) as we go, but I will have to think more about is_trivially_copyable :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you're incrementing a `void` pointer.
What is the size of `void`??

You should cast the pointer to the correct type before incrementing it.
`sizeof` gives the size in bytes so the correct type should be `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`.

`*buffer = (uint8_t*)(*buffer) + sizeof(unsigned int);`